# Get ip from the machine in Angular to store

Tags: angular, parsing, ip

I have a project in which I make a query, which return some data. This data is passed to a cancel service, but the data is different. These data are matched through a parse. However, the cancellation service passes 2 additional fields: user code and machine code. The user code I get to you, but the machine code (IP) in angular to me is new. I would like help on how to get the number and pass on a variable, this ip.

Answer (score 0):

Angular (and the client side in general) knows nothing about network layer details like the client IP. If you make an http request to a server, the application on the server handling the request has access to the client's IP and can record and store it.

Tldr. This isn't something related to Angular. The is a server side concern.